# How to stop MATLAB clipping the title of a figure when I print

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

When I create a figure with MATLAB with a title, then use the File|Print option to print the figure, the title is clipped. Please try this code for an example

```
t = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
s = sin(t);
figure
plot(t,s)
titleString = sprintf('Multi\nLine\nTitle');
title(titleString)
disp('Now press File|Print Preview on the figure and observe that the title is clipped.')
disp('This happens with all titles, the multi line title makes it more obvious.')
disp('I know I can fix it with Fill Page or Center, but I should not have too.')
```

You can also see the problem in print preview. As I say in the example code, I know I can get round the problem using Print Preview then Fill Page or Center, but I don't want people using my code to have to use a work around.

I have observed this problem with r2014a and r2015b. I assume other releasse are also affected.

Is there setting I can make before creating the figure that centres the plot or fills the page and makes the problem go away? Is there some other setting I should make to avoid the problem?

Here is a little more debug information. If I press File|Print Preview, MATLAB reports Left 0.64, Top -0.59, Width 20.32, Height 15.24. I guess the problem is related to the negative Top value. These are defaults from MATLAB; I have not made any attempt to change these values.

One extra thing. I am in the UK, so my default paper/printer setting will be for A4 paper, if that makes a difference.

Edit:

It looks like my problems are caused by two lines further up in my program:

```
set(0,'DefaultFigurePaperOrientation','landscape')
set(0,'DefaultFigurePaperType','A4')
```

I think that becuase plots expect to be on paper with a portrait orientation, I am seeing these problems.

Perhaps I should revise my question to: what to I need to change in MATLAB figures so they print correctly on landscape A4 paper (ideally in the center, scaled to fill the page, but with correct orientation). All this without using Print Preview.

But I am going to do this instead to code around my problem.

```
set(0,'DefaultFigurePaperOrientation','portrait')
set(0,'DefaultFigurePaperType','A4')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reproduce your problem on the computer I'm currently on (see the values I'm getting by default - Top is `8.11`):

[image]

---

However, if your problem is what I think it is (I'm getting something that fits this description on another computer I'm working on), try adding `_{ }` at the end of your string. This is a TeX string meaning "subscripted space" which pushes the rest of the text slightly upward. You can also use `^{ }` on the first line if the clipping is happening from the top. I found this workaround to work on axis titles and labels as well.

Exaggerated, the workaround looks like this:

```
titleString = sprintf('^{^{^{^{^{^{ }}}}}}Multi\nLine\nTitle');
```

Which shows the word "Multi" even for `Top = -0.59`.

If the above is not what you're looking for, you might want to look at the robust [`export_fig`](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I can't reproduce it either any more and I am wondering if it is associated with the default Style Sheet you see on the print preview. Mine has changed from Landscape to Portrait and now has reasonable Left and Top values. I didn't do anything deliberate to make this change. The style sheet also seems common to both versions of MATLAB. I will keep investigating and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that my clipping problems are caused by this line:

```
set(0,'DefaultFigurePaperOrientation','landscape')
```

I have revised my program to start with this instead.

```
set(0,'DefaultFigurePaperOrientation','portrait')
set(0,'DefaultFigurePaperType','A4')
```

And the problem has gone away.

Users can still print in landscape if they use the print preview feature.